# How to find the first solution only with this backtracking

Tags: java, recursion, solution, backtracking

i'm trying to write a Sudoku solver which will return only the first possible solution.
i managed to print all possible solutions with void methods but i can't stop on the first find.

i know the preferred way is to switch to boolean methods and return `true` up the tree - 
but i can't find the right way to write it.

any way i tried always give compilation errors (`method must return boolean`).

```
public boolean recursiveSolve(int line, int column) {
    if(line == N) // N is the board size (9)
        return true;
    // if Cell is not empty - continue
    if(board1.getCell(line, column) != 0) { 
        return nextCell(line, column);
    }
    // if Cell empty - solve
    else { 
        for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            board1.setCell(line, column, i); // set value to cell
            if(board1.boardIsOk())           // check if the board is legal
                return nextCell(line, column); // continue
        }
        board1.setCell(line, column, 0);     // backtrack
    }
}

private boolean nextCell(int line, int column) {
    if(column < 8)
        return recursiveSolve(line, column+1); // progress up the row
    else
        return recursiveSolve(line+1, 0);      // progress down the lines
}
```

Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't a Sudoku have only one solution?

Comment: where is .boardIsOk() coming from? Also, something tells me that you should be storing nextCell to a variable, and checking the value of that var on each run of your for loop. Once the val hits something you want, then return.

Comment: @EmilVikström: Concider one activates this method with an empty board..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is some pseudocode for most recursive backtracking problems.

> If you are already at a solution, report success.
>
> for (every possible choice in the current position )  {
>
> Make that choice and take one step along the path.
>
> Use recursion to solve the problem from the new position.
>
> If the recursive call succeeds, report the success to the next higher
>   level.
>
> Back out of the current choice to restore the state at the beginning
>   of the loop.
>
> }
>
> Report failure.

Here is some actual code based on a lecture from Stanford. I re-wrote it in java and included comments.

```
Boolean SolveSudoku(int[][] grid)
{
    int row, col;

    if(!FindUnassignedLocation(grid, row, col))
        //all locations successfully assigned
        return true;

    for(int num = 1; num <= 9; num++)
    {
        //if number is allowed to be placed in the square
        if(NoConflicts(grid, row, col, num))
        {
            //place the number in the square
            grid[row][col] = num;

            //recur, if successful then stop
            if(SolveSudoku(grid))
                return true;

            //undo and try again
            grid[row][col] = UNASSIGNED;
        }
     }
     //this triggers backtracking from early decisions
     return false;
}
```

You just need to implement a few methods, which are pretty trivial.

Comment: thanks guys. indeed the whole structure of my code was wrong, so i couldn't end the backtracking when i wanted. changing to the pattern above works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
        if(board1.boardIsOk())           // check if the board is legal
            return nextCell(line, column); // continue
```

into

```
        if(board1.boardIsOk()) {          // check if the board is legal
            boolean solved = nextCell(line, column); // continue
            if (solved) {
                return true;
            ]
        }
    ...
    return false;
```

Comment: @Kristian now understand you delivered the solution too.